# How to quit GRUB2 pager early?

Tags: grub2

Somehow the GRUB2 pager scrolls only about one line per 2 seconds, so it takes absolutely forever to boot after [enabling the pager and debug messages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Enable_debug_messages). Is there any way to quit this pager when it's at the `MORE` prompt rather than scrolling through debug output for hours before continuing the boot process? I've tried <kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, and other random keys.